# Initializing variables in Swift without var/let

Tags: swift, var, let, for-in-loop

I'm new to Swift so this might come as a noob question but I will be thankful if someone cleared the doubt because I cannot find any explanation online. While using for-in loop, sometimes the variables have not been initialized before and still there is no compiler error. Sometimes if I try to write var/let before them, it shows error- **'let' pattern cannot appear nested in an already immutable context**

e.g., in the code below, why have the variables movie and releasedDate not been initialized before?

```
class MovieArchive {
func filterByYear(year:Int, movies:Dictionary<String, Int> ) -> [String]{
    var filteredArray = [String]()
    for (movie, releaseDate) in movies {
        if year == releaseDate {
            filteredArray.append(movie)
        }
    }
    return filteredArray
}

}

var aiThemedMovies = ["Metropolis": 1927, "2001: A Space Odyssey": 1968, "Blade Runner": 1982, "War Games": 1983, "Terminator": 1984, "The Matrix": 1999, "A.I.": 2001, "Her": 2013, "Ex Machina": 2015]

var myArchive = MovieArchive()
myArchive.filterByYear(year: 2013
, movies: aiThemedMovies)
```

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: Please show an example where the error message you described does appear.

Comment: "e.g., in the code below, why have the variables movie and releasedDate not been initialized before?" Because this is how the language works. You might enjoy reading the Swift ebook provided by Apple.

Comment: Your code works fine on my Playground.

Comment: @appzYourLife Sir/Ma'am the code is without error but if I try to write var before movie or releaseDate the following error comes **/Variable 'movie' was never mutated; consider changing to 'let' constant** and if I write let, the error is **let' pattern cannot appear nested in an already immutable context** and this happens only at some places. In many for-in loop, it asks me to write var. Thank You for the concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift does initialise `movie` and `releaseDate` using `let`, but simplifies that initialisation so that you can just assume that they're set to the correct variables from `movies` every time the loop iterates. That's why you don't need to write let before `movie` and `releaseDate`.

If you write var in front of the variable, you can mutate the value in the array that it points to. If it's a let, then it won't let you mutate it.

For example, if you place var in front of one of the variables, this code will change all the `releaseDates` to 2000:

```
class MovieArchive {
    func filterByYear(year:Int, movies:Dictionary<String, Int> ) -> [String]{
        var filteredArray = [String]()
        for (movie, var releaseDate) in movies {
            releaseDate = 2000
            if year == releaseDate {
                filteredArray.append(movie)
            }
        }
        return filteredArray
    }
}
```

Comment: So is the default initialization set to let? Because if I make changes on the movie variable, it prompts me to initialize as var. I'm just confused as to when to use var and when not to. Thank You for the concern.

Comment: @AnuritaSrivastava Updated my answer :)

Comment: I'm aware that var is used for non-constant variables, and so your code works without error when I declare releaseDate in next line, but if I don't then it shows error. Why does that happen?

Comment: It's because if you don't mutate releaseDate, there's no point in setting it as a var. Swift detects that it hasn't been mutated so then gives an error asking you to remove var.

Comment: Thank You. I understood the concept now. :)

Answer (score 1):

Without concerning ourselves with practical usage, let's just talk about what is syntactically legal in a `for` loop. This is legal:

```
    for var i in 1...3 { // ok
        print(i)
        i = 0
    }
```

This is not legal:

```
    for let i in 1...3 { // error
        print(i)
    }
```

Why? Because the `let` is *implicit* when you say this:

```
    for i in 1...3 { // ok
        print(i)
    }
```

You didn't say `var`, so `i` is automatically declared with `let`. It's just a way of making your life simpler. Don't worry, be happy.

Comment: I'm sorry but my question is about not using any of these and also it shows an error when I write var. So is it syntactically correct to write      `for i in 1....3 { }`  ?

Comment: I know it shows an error when you write `var`. But _I_ showed you how to write `var` and _not_ get an error. You will not learn if you don't look and listen.

Answer (score 0):

`(movie, releaseDate)` is a tuple of variables. Swift allows initialising multiple variables at once using tuples.

```
let (movie, releaseDate) = ("Metropolis", 1927)
```

A `for-in` loop is syntactic sugar to redeclare those constants for each element of your collection. In that case, `let` is implicit.

There are other ways to get named constants with implicit `let`, like using a *closure*:

```
class MovieArchive {
    func filterByYear(year: Int, movies: [String: Int]) -> [String] {
        return movies.filter { (movie, releaseDate) -> Bool in
            year == releaseDate
            }.map { $0.key }
    }
}
```

The above example gives the same results as your code by the way.

But apart from `for-in`, func parameters and closures, I can't think of other cases where the `let`/`var` keyword would be omitted in Swift 3.0.

Comment: So I'm just confused as to when to use var and when not to. Like why do we do this? Thank You for the concern.

Comment: @AnuritaSrivastava almost always use var/let. I can only think of omission in the two cases previously described, `for-in` and closures. Also, there are sometimes implicit variables/constants, like `self`, `$0`, `error` (in a `do-catch`)

Comment: Thank you for the insight! :)